# Get value from respective Span on Mouse click on table column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

How to get the time value shown below, from respective span on mouse click on below table column which has dropdowns.
For Ex: If I click on any dropdowns in the 1st column, I need to get the time `06:30 PM - 03:30 AM` in the 1st column (shown on top).
If I click on any dropdowns in the 2nd column, I need to get the time in 2nd column and so on.. using Jquery.

[image]

Below is the table html structure:

[image]

Below is the span shown inside the div:

[image]

JavaScript:

```
function drpdwn_resource(resourceElement, resourceObj, isEmpty, startTimeSlot, endTimeSlot, showId, workOrderId) {    
var resourceData = [];
resourceData.push(resourceObj);
$(resourceElement).select2({
    data: resourceData,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    placeholder: '(Empty)',
    allowClear: true,
}).on('select2:open', function (e) {        
    $(resourceElement + ' option[value]').remove();
    //CRM Data
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DailyJobSchedule/GetResources",
        type: "POST",
        data: { start: startTimeSlot, end: endTimeSlot },
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            for (var data in response) {
                var newOption = new Option(response[data].text, response[data].id, false, false);
                $(resourceElement).append(newOption).trigger('change');
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log('failure');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

C#:

```
for (var i in workOrderList) {
        //console.log("=========================");
        $('.resource-popup').append("<li class='orkOrderlist'>\
                                                <div class='innerdiv"+ i + "'>\
                                                <div class='c-job-title job-dtls-clm border-btm'>"+ workOrderList[i].ServiceAccountName + "&nbsp(" + workOrderList[i].BoothNumber + ")</div>\
                                                <div class='c-job-time border-btm job-dtls-clm'>\
                                                <span class='job-start-tm'>"+ moment(workOrderList[i].StartTime).format('hh:mm A') + "</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span class='job-end-tm'>"
            + moment(workOrderList[i].EndTime).format('hh:mm A') + "</span>\
                                                </div>");
```

Comment: And what did you tried? Please insert your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/closest and https://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: Could you replace your image with the div that contains the dropdowns expanded, please?  I assume that's the last div in the image.  Even better, copy and paste the html into a code block.  Since you have jQuery to work with, the solution is easier than the current answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [target.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) functions to achieve this without jQuery.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.job-start-tm')
   .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', event => 
   console.log(event.target.innerHTML))
)
```

```html
<span class="job-start-tm">14:20</span>
<span class="job-start-tm">15:50</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span'){
        console.log(e.target.innerText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it's fairly trivial.

I'm waiting for you to edit the question to show the dropdown elements (and hopefully post the html and css source, rather than a screenshot), after which I'll edit this answer.

In the meantime, I'll assume

- the dropdowns are `<select>`s
- it is always the last row that contains the selects
- there are always exactly two columns per table column
- the second to last row that contains the value you wish to grab

If any of these assumptions are wrong, the code is pretty easy to weak.

```js
$('.resource-group')                  // select the table
  .on('click', 
    // target the last row of each item, and then the <select> within that row
    '.orkOrderlist > div > :last-child select',
    e => {                            // add a single click handler on *the table*
      let $sel = $(e.target),         // capture the clicked <select>
        spanSelector =
          $sel.is(':first-child') ?   // determine which column <span> contains the value
            'span.job-start-tm' :     // selector for first <span>
            'span.job-end-tm',        // selector for last <span>
        $valueSpan =
          $sel.parent().prev()        // capture the row above the <select>s
            .children(spanSelector);  // capture the desired <span>

      console.log($valueSpan.text()); // do something with the value
    }
  );
```

```css
ul.resource-group {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.orkOrderlist {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 10%);
}

.c-job-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.job-dtls-clm {
  padding: 4px;
}

select {
  border: none;
}

select:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="resource-group">
  <li class="orkOrderlist">
    <div class="innerdiv0">
      <div class="c-job-title border-bottom job-dtls-clm">Royal BC Museum&nbsp;(1446)</div>
      <div class="c-job-time border-bottom job-dtls-clm">
        <span class="job-start-tm">6:30 PM</span>
        &nbsp;-&nbsp;
        <span class="job-end-tm">3:30 AM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex border-bottom job-dtls-clm">
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="w-auto">
          <option>(Empty)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="orkOrderlist">
    <div class="innerdiv1">
      <div class="c-job-title border-bottom job-dtls-clm">Gwinnet Place Honda&nbsp;(1347)</div>
      <div class="c-job-time border-bottom job-dtls-clm">
        <span class="job-start-tm">6:30 PM</span>
        &nbsp;-&nbsp;
        <span class="job-end-tm">3:30 AM</span>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex border-bottom job-dtls-clm">
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
        </select>
        <select class="w-auto">
          <option>(Empty)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously, I was extra verbose in order to illustrate each step.  You could shorten the code considerably into about 3-5 lines with some jQuery jiu jitsu.

There are two advantages of this method over the previous two answers:

1. There's only one function and only one listener in memory, no matter how many columns you have.  In the unlikely case that you have thousands of items, this optimization can improve performance considerably.
2. This works no matter how many rows are in each item's column.

Depending on what you intend to do with the captured values, it is very easy to tweak this code since you already have the selected elements.  For example, if the items have multiple row values you want to capture with each dropdown click, you can simply replace `.prev()` with `.prevAll()` and call `.map()` or `.each()` to do something with each value, or call `.join()` to generate a single string containing all of the values.

It would also be easy to change this from working on 2 columns to working on *n* columns.  Capture the `<select>`'s index within its row, and change the span selector to `` `> span:nth-child(${n})` ``.